# Acro: Adjusting the spacing after \acl if the long form has italic shape

Tags: spacing, italic, acro

I am using the `acro` package to manage my acronyms. Some of the terms are set in italic. When using `\acl`, the spacing after the term does not get adjusted.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[20pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn,]{scrbook}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[sort, macros = true]{acro}
  \DeclareAcronym{aureus}{short=S. aureus , long=Staphylococcus aureus ,
                          long-format=\itshape , short-format=\itshape}


\begin{document}

\chapter{\acl{aureus}--- vs. \textit{tests}--- any way to adjust the spacing after the
         italic long form inserted by acro?}

\end{document}
```

The em dash has larger spacing after `\textit{tests}` than after `\acl{aureus}`.
Is there a way to adjust the spacing after italic shaped `acro` terms?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You can use `long-format=\textit` instead of `long-format=\itshape`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213571/acro-adjusting-the-spacing-after-acl-if-the-long-form-has-italic-shape#comment500511_213571): `acro`'s options regarding formatting accept code whose last macro may need a mandatory argument (if this shouldn't work for a formatting option I'd consider this an error on my part and would appreciate a message!). The contents of said argument will be the corresponding entry. So I would recommend using

```
\DeclareAcronym{aureus}{
  short=S. aureus ,
  long=Staphylococcus aureus ,
  long-format=\textit , % <===
  short-format=\textit  % <===
}
```

since `\textit` adds italic correction after its argument.

Answer (score 1):

As cgnieder correctly commented:

Using `long-format=\textit` instead of `long-format=\itshape` does the trick.